# How to tweet with screenshot in unity webgl

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to tweet with screenshot of unity WebGL game integrated with React.
In Unity Editor, screenshot and tweet is going well, but if I build WebGL, I can't upload image.
What happened...?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#endif

public class TweetWithScreenShot : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _imgurClientId;

#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern string TweetFromUnity(string rawMessage);
#endif

    public void TweetWithScreenshot()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TweetWithScreenshotCo());
    }

    private IEnumerator TweetWithScreenshotCo()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Texture2D tex = ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture();

        var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
        wwwForm.AddField("image", Convert.ToBase64String(tex.EncodeToJPG()));
        wwwForm.AddField("type", "base64");

        // Upload to Imgur
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", wwwForm);
        www.SetRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", "Client-ID " + _imgurClientId);

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        var uri = "";

        if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);
            uri = xDoc.Element("data")?.Element("link")?.Value;

            // Remove Ext
            uri = uri?.Remove(uri.Length - 4, 4);
        }
        print("imgur------ "+uri);
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
        TweetFromUnity($"Tweet Message%0a{uri}");
#endif
    }
}
```

this is the following code snap.

Comment: Do you get errors? You can open the developer console of your browser and get a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: Yes, In the console of the browser, I got too many request error 429.

Comment: why `if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)`? I would rather first of all check for `if(www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)` and in any other case do `Debug.LogError($"{www.result} - {www.responseCode}: {www.error}")`

Comment: and well [HTTP Code 429 => Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) means you tried to often and now the page is blocking the requests from your device ^^